# vsto find goes infinite

Tags: c#, ms-word, automation, vsto

```
            var intFound = 0;
            if (searchRange.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref
            missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref
            missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing))
                while (rng.Find.Found)
                {
                        intFound++;
                        rng.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBlue;

                    }
```

In the above code, if I add any other actions like add an index field or a messagebox.show makes the loop goes endless. Can any one help me understand where am I going wrong?

Comment: yes - your code reads - while found (which you never change) keep looping..   you maybe meant to loop through something?

Comment: Once I found I need to again find the adjacent “.”  Or “;” or “.” Whichever comes first and expand selection and change the colour of whole text. Is this possible?

Comment: Loop on Execute, not Find.Found. Yes, your second question is possible, check out the API and try it out, if you can't figure it out after a reasonable amount of effort, post your code in a separate question.